# How should I authenticate my socket after authenticating my user in redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, socket.io, redux

onSubmit > userAction.login > dispatch "SUCCESS_AUTHENTICATE" > set token of user and socket state in their reducers > ????? how can I then make socket.emit("authenticate", {token}) happen?

Answer (score 0):

Winded up just writing a short middleware, working perfectly.

```
const socketAuthenticator = (store) => (next) => (action) =>{
    if(action.type === "AUTHENTICATION_FULFILLED" || action.type === "REGISTRATION_FULFILLED") {
        const token = action.payload.token;
        const socket = store.getState().socket.socket
        socket.emit('authenticate', { token })
    }
    next(action)
}
```